# React MUI multiple select render selected value as Chip

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to figure how can I render Chip on MUI multiple select components that will act like the checkmarks from the docs.

The component from the docs:
[image]

Is it possible to render multiple Chip separate by "," and not expand the select input?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the input from growing when you select more options you can use the Autocomplete component that has a `limitTags` prop where you define how many chips should be displayed **when the input is out of focus**.

[limitTags prop being used to limit the number of chips displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9ILp.png)

Comment: No thanks, I don't want to switch the functionality, so you don't know if is possible with multiple select?

Comment: It is not possible with multiple select, but using Autocomplete wouldn't change the functionality.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try.